# Why is the derivative of the product of a vector and its transpose cTc2 c?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm learning principal component analysis and i have to derive the result that will minimize the error $$c^* = \arg \min{[x-g(c)]^2} = \arg \min{[x-g(c)]^\mathsf{T}[x-g(c)]}$$.

What I have done so far is to simplify the error by expanding the argument, replacing $g(c)$ by its definition $g(c)=Dc$, and use the fact that $D\mathsf{T}D=I$:

$c^* = \arg \min [{x^\mathsf{T}x - 2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + g(c)^\mathsf{T}g(c)}]$

$c^* = x^\mathsf{T}x - \arg \min {[ -2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + g(c)^\mathsf{T}g(c)}]$

$c^* = x^\mathsf{T}x - \arg \min {[ -2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + (Dc)^\mathsf{T}(Dc)]}$

$c^* = x^\mathsf{T}x - \arg \min{[ -2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + c^\mathsf{T}D^\mathsf{T}Dc}]$

$c^* = x^\mathsf{T}x - \arg \min{[ -2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + c^\mathsf{T}Ic]}$

$c^* = x^\mathsf{T}x - \arg \min{[ -2x^\mathsf{T}g(c) + c^\mathsf{T}c]}$

$(−2x^\mathsf{T}Dc + c^\mathsf{T}c) = 0$

$-2D^\mathsf{T}x+2c=0$

$c=D^\mathsf{T}x$